# How do i get full html content of a remote url using jquery

Tags: jquery

How do i get full html content of a remote url using jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly - AJAX requests are only allowed to the same domain as your site content. There are many work-arounds however, have a look at [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj) for an overview. Your best bet would be to create a "service" on your server that will download the content on behalf of an AJAX request.